# screenrc: How to map "alt+number" to “select a screen window” in gnome terminal

Tags: bash, gnu-screen, gnome-terminal

I found this online:

```
bindkey "\261" select 1
bindkey "\262" select 2 
bindkey "\263" select 3 
....
```

Basically it maps <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to "select 1"; <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> to "select 2". So when you press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, it is supposed to jump to screen window 1.

This works in `xterm` but not but in `gnome-terminal`. I know `gnome-terminal` already uses <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to switch to tab *n*. So I turned off this key mapping for gnome terminal in `gnome configure editor`. But it still doesn't work.

Seems that when I press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, it is received by `bash`, not by the GNU screen program, so it puts a special character on the bash or puts `"arg: 1"`.

Any solutions? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is caused by different treatment of the Meta key (Alt on PC keyboards) by Xterm and GNOME Terminal.

In Xterm, holding the Meta key will (by default) set the highest bit on the characters (<kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> becomes `\261`), while GNOME Terminal and most other terminal emulators leave the character unmodified but prefix it with an `ESC` (the same keypress becomes `\033\061`).

There doesn't seem to be a way to configure the handling of Meta key in GNOME Terminal (`printf '\033[?1036l'` may work, but I cannot test it), so you will have to somehow bind `\033\061` to "`select 1`" and so on. (It's highly unlikely that it'll actually work, and if it did, it would probably break every other special key out there: arrows, function keys, etc.)

Comment: HI grawity, it works when binding "\033\061" to "select 1". Awesome!!! Thank you so much. Right now, it doesn't break anytings like arrows or function keys. let's see. Again, many thanks!

Comment: The reason that GNOME Terminal and most other terminal emulators these days encode Alt as an ESC prefix is that setting the Meta bit collides with character encodings beyond 7-bit ASCII.

Comment: Hi ak2, Thanks for commenting the reason.

Comment: grawity is right, the binding is breaking some things, for me I cannot type Chinese character 花 anymore.